# Is there a way to get a status through MS Teams, Azure, OneDrive or something else?

Tags: microsoft-teams, user-presence

I tried to get the status through the Microsoft Graph. On many ways!
I tried to get the last login or to get the status of a token. But I think there is no way.

But ... we are using much more than the O365 login.
So, do anybody know, if there is a way to get a status through MS Teams, Azure, OneDrive or something else?

I don't want to install extra software on all the End User PCs.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "status"?

Comment: Sry, I need the precense of my teammades.
So I mean the online-status.

Answer (score 1):

Presence is not currently available via Microsoft Graph. There is an open [UserVoice suggestion for this](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17714167-skype-lync-in-microsoft-graph-such-as-presence) that could use additional votes.